# Drag big picture in small layer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, image, layer

I need a plugin for jquery or another js framework, where I can define a small div where i can drag around a big picture, so i get only a clipping of the picture. any ideas?

edit: i try to explain

i have a small div, like 600px x 450px. this div behaves like a clipping window for a big picture with like 3000px x 2000px. so i only see a specific cutout of the big picture. and i need to drag that big picture around in this small clipping window!

c

Comment: google it man. this there are many implementations that are only a search away

Comment: What do you mean by "a clipping of the picture"? This question is vague and I think needs to be edited to be answerable.